# Shouldn't $\mathrm{End}_{C(TM)}(E)$ be defined differently in Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators?

Tags: modules, clifford-algebras, super-algebra

The first four chapters of the book lead up to the proof of theorem 4.1. Its main consequence is that it provides the local index theorem for Dirac operators. The statement of theorem 4.1 involves a function
\begin{equation}
C(TM)\otimes\mathrm{End}_{C(TM)}(E)\to\mathrm{End}(E),
\end{equation}
where $\mathrm{End}_{C(TM)}(E)$ is defined as follows on page 104:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dim. euclidean vector space. If $E$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded Clifford module, we denote by $\mathrm{End}_{C(V)}(E)$ the algebra of endomorphisms
> of $E$ super-commuting with the action of $C(V)$.

### Shouldn't "super-commuting" be replaced by "commuting"?

Here is my reasoning: In short, I think that the derivation of the crucial formula
$$\mathrm{str}_E(a\otimes b)=(-2i)^{n/2}\sigma_n(a)\mathrm{str}_{E/S}(b)$$
for $a\in C(V)$ and $b\in\mathrm{End}_{C(V)}(E)$ on page 146 assumes that $b$ commutes with the Clifford action:

Let $T\in L(S\otimes W,E)$ be the isomorphism of Clifford modules introduced in proposition 3.27. $T$ is even and commutes with the Clifford action. I assume that the isomorphism $$C(V)\otimes\mathrm{End}_{C(V)}(E)\to\mathrm{End}(E)$$ maps $a\otimes b$ to $T\circ(c_S(a)\otimes b/S)\circ T^{-1}$, where $b/S\in\mathrm{End}(W)$ is defined by$$T\circ (1\otimes b/S)\circ T^{-1}=b.$$(Of course this requires that $b$ commutes with the Clifford action.) Then
$$\mathrm{str}_E(a\otimes b)=\mathrm{str}_E(T\circ(c_S(a)\otimes b/S)\circ T^{-1})=\mathrm{str}_{S\otimes W}(c_S(a)\otimes b/S)=\underbrace{\mathrm{str}_S(c_S(a))}_{=(2/i)^{n/2}\sigma_n(a)}\underbrace{\mathrm{str}_W(b/S)}_{=\mathrm{str}_{E/S}(b)}$$ which is the desired formula.

Comment: Careful! Those tensor products are all $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-graded tensor products, which are perhaps best written as $\widehat{\otimes}$ to remind you that they’re $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-graded. For example, if $\phi \in \operatorname{End}(W)$ is odd, then $$\forall s \in S, \, \forall w \in W, \quad (1 \mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}} \phi)(s \otimes w) = \gamma_S(s) \otimes w,$$ where $\gamma_S$ is the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-grading operator on $S$. You need to go back to Section 1.2 of Berline–Getzler–Vergne and reread it with exceptional care—this stuff trips people up all the time.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thank you for the comment. AFAIU you suggest that the function$$\mathrm{End}(W)\to\mathrm{End}_{C(V)}(E)$$does not map $A$ to $1\otimes A$, but instead to $1\mathbin{\hat\otimes}A$. This makes sense since the latter super-commutes with the Clifford action, but then the crucial formula$$\mathrm{str}_W(A)=\mathrm{str}_{E/S}(A)$$is wrong for odd $A$, isn't it? (I can add my calculation to my question.) So I still believe that my initial guess is correct.

Comment: My apologies for the typo, it should be $(1 \mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}} \phi)(s \otimes w) = \gamma_S(s) \otimes \phi(w)$. As for your calculation, there's something not quite right, again involving "super" conventions, but I'll need to think about it more carefully.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić No problem, the typo didn't cause any confusion. Please keep me updated in case that you further think about the issue.

Comment: And please let me know if I should clarify some part of my reasoning.

Comment: I think that we want to use the formula$$\mathrm{str}_{S\otimes W}(A\otimes B)=\mathrm{str}_{S}(A)\mathrm{str}_{W}( B)$$(assuming that $\gamma_{S\otimes W}=\gamma_S\otimes\gamma_W$) and this formula is not generally true if $A\otimes B$ is replaced by $A\mathbin{\hat\otimes}B$ (is it?).